SharePoint Managed accounts how to get this to work without causing the farm to go down every cycle?
Following the instructions on this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-automatic-password-change
We added our farm account to this service.     Now when the automatic update of the password occurs, the SharePoint farm goes down.   The services that are using the farm account: SharePoint timer service, SharePoint caching etc.  all fail due to login failure.  As the service changed the password, we do not know what the new password is.
I was hoping his is an automated process would help make the accounts more secure and keep this process running seamlessly but it turns out to cause a total system failure every time it changes the password.
Has anyone got this to work without taking down the farm?
We tried the instructions provided in this article:
Following the instructions on this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-automatic-password-change
But when the service takes down the farm.   The only way we can get the farm back up is to change the password back to a documented password from when we first setup the farm.   We did this as we do not know all the nuances of where this account was used when setting up SharePoint.   It always seems like me miss a setting somewhere that holds the login information when we try to manually set a new password.
